# Plotting 3d surface and some points with Haskell to gnuplot wrapper package

Tags: haskell, gnuplot

I have [gnuplot](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gnuplot) package installed.

Is there a way to draw 3d surface and some points on it (i. e. I need it all in 1 place)?

The surface is defined by function, and points -- by coordinates.

I can't find normal documentation for it, and can't totally understand the source of this package (it's too big and complicated for me).

I can find, how to do it apart, but I need it to be together. And I can't find example to do so.

If there is such way, I need documentation, or example for it.

Please help me to solve the problem. Thank you in advance!

****UPD****

**Requested code**

```
module Main where

import qualified Graphics.Gnuplot.Advanced as GP

import qualified Graphics.Gnuplot.MultiPlot as MultiPlot

import qualified Graphics.Gnuplot.Frame as Frame
import qualified Graphics.Gnuplot.Frame.OptionSet as Opts
import qualified Graphics.Gnuplot.Frame.OptionSet.Style as OptsStyle
import qualified Graphics.Gnuplot.Frame.OptionSet.Histogram as Histogram

import qualified Graphics.Gnuplot.Graph as Graph

import qualified Graphics.Gnuplot.Plot.ThreeDimensional as Plot3D
import qualified Graphics.Gnuplot.Graph.ThreeDimensional as Graph3D

import qualified Graphics.Gnuplot.Plot.TwoDimensional as Plot2D
import qualified Graphics.Gnuplot.Graph.TwoDimensional as Graph2D
import Graphics.Gnuplot.Plot.TwoDimensional (linearScale, )

import qualified Graphics.Gnuplot.LineSpecification as LineSpec

import qualified Data.Time as Time

--import qualified Paths_gnuplot as Path
import System.FilePath ((</>), )

import Data.Array (listArray, )
import Data.Foldable (foldMap, )
import Data.Monoid (mappend, )

list2d :: Plot2D.T Int Integer
list2d =
   Plot2D.list Graph2D.listPoints [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13::Integer]

wave3d :: Frame.T (Graph3D.T Double Double Double)
wave3d =
   let meshNodes = linearScale 100 (-2,2)
   in  Frame.cons
          (Opts.grid True $
           Opts.xRange3d (-2.5,2.5) $
           Opts.yRange3d (-2.5,2.5) $
           defltOpts) $
        Plot3D.surface
          meshNodes meshNodes
          (\x y -> sqrt(x*y))

defltOpts :: Graph.C graph => Opts.T graph
defltOpts =
   Opts.key False $
   Opts.deflt

main :: IO ()
main = sequence_ $
   GP.plotDefault list2d : -- I want points like there, but in 3d, determined by coordinates list
   GP.plotDefault wave3d : -- and surface like there
   []
```

Comment: Please show the two separate scripts that you have, because I don't really get what you want.

Comment: Honestly, I found the Haskell gnuplot package unintuitive so I just used a temporary directory and called the `gnuplot` binary directly when I needed something similar.

Comment: @Bernhard 

>Adding requested code in question.